# What happens to fork when you delete your repo after switching it from public to private?

Tags: git, github, version-control

My question is what happens to forks for a public repo that is turned private and then deleted? And does forking when it's private or public make a difference in this situation?

What I understood from the GitHub docs is:

- Deleting a private repo will delete all of its forks
- Deleting a public repo will keep its forks, and the ownership will be transferred to another user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://help.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility

> If a public repository is made private, its public forks are split off into a new network.

Deleting your private repository after that doesn't affect the new network, all public repositories stay public.

> one of the existing public forks is chosen to be the new parent repository and all other repositories are forked off of this new parent.